# On why $d/dz(\Re(z))$ does not exist

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f(z)=\Re(z)\in\mathbb{C}$, $z=x+iy$ and $h=h_x+ih_y$, then

$$f'(z)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$$
$$= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h_x+i(y+h_y))-f(x+iy)}{h}$$
$$= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\Re(x+h_x+i(y+h_y))-\Re(x+iy)}{h}$$
$$= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{x+h_x-x}{h}$$
$$= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\Re(h)}{h}$$
now, as we take the limit, it's worth considering how our expression behaves depending on where we take the limit from. If we consider what happens as we take the limit as $h\to0$ along the real axis, we have that $\Re(h)=h$, hence the ratio between $\Re(h)$ and $h$ is $1$, and the limit hence is $1$. However, if we repeat this process, but along the imaginary axis, we find that $\Re(h)=0$, and hence the ratio between $\Re(h)$ and $h$ is $0$, and our limit evaluates to $0$. We notice that already, the limit approaches different values as $h\to0$.

My question, then, is whether or not it is therefore safe to say that the limit of the difference quotient does not exist, and that therefore, $f(z)$ is not differentiable, or are there other conditions that we need to check before we jump to such a conclusion?

Comment: You (correctly) demonstrated that the function is not complex differentiable.

Comment: @MartinR So in other words this is all we need? We don't need to consider any other arguments as long as there are two that cause the limit to approach different values?

Comment: The derivative of a function $f$ at a point $z_0$ is a number $f'(z_0)$ such that $f(z_0+z)$ looks like $f(z_0)+f'(z_0)z$ for small $z$ (and a strict definition of "looks like", involving limits and stuff). Letting $t\in \Bbb R$ be small, we see that $\Re(z_0+t)$ looks like $\Re(z_0)+1 t$, while $\Re(z_0+ti)$ looks like $\Re(z_0)+0t$. So there is no single number fulfilling the role of derivative and the function is therefore not differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly demonstrate this, you prove that the limit does not exist. Another way of prove this is using the so-called Cauchy-Riemman equations, it is easily proof that if a funcion is holomorphic if and only if the real part function and the imaginary part function are differentiable as funcions on $\mathbb{R}²$ and the Cauchy-Riemman equations holds, they are $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = - v_x$. It follows that if $f: \Omega \subset \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ is holomorphic then $v_y = 0$ and $v_x = 0$ then $f$ is constant(Assuming $\Omega$ is conected).